# Broadly override an operator (Type check with "==")

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, operator-overloading

Is there a way to make Python (3.6.3) throw an error for comparing two objects with different types? As an example, I would like `"2" == 2` to throw an error rather than return `False`.

Naively, I could add `type(a) == type(b)` along with `a == b` in the conditional, but I am hoping for a simpler solution; like replacing `==` with another symbol(s).

In a similar context, I like that in Python comparing between a `str` and an `int` results in a type mismatch error. For example, `"2" >= 2` throws an error. But I am looking for the same behavior for an equality `==`.

PS: I think I miscommunicated the question a bit. To be precise, I am looking for a simple alternative to `==` that throws an error with different types; instead of overriding the behavior of `==` broadly.

Comment: How would python know what class combinations you want to throw an error and which should perform the comparison? You would probably want `str` <-> `int` to fail, but what about `int` <-> `float`? What about when custom classes are involved?

Comment: I can imagine this will also break a lot of third-party dependencies if you applied it globally. It's not a good idea to change a basic behavior of a programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. A dumb question though, why having different types cause an error for `>=` but not for `==`? and why isn't the behavior consistent between the two?

Comment: When checking if "2" >= 3, would you want it to check if the value 2 was greater than 3, or the ascii value of the character "2" was greater? Its ambiguous, so it doesn't make sense to compare different types in that way

Comment: @CHaworth, but doesn't that ambiguity hold for `==` as well?

Comment: `2 == "2"` is absolutely not ambiguous.

Comment: Think of it this way, when you are checking if two objects (a & b) are equal, you consider treating both objects as the type of object a if you check a ==b, or both objects as the type of object b if you check b == a (not exactly how it works, just trying to illustrate). Either way you should get the same result. For ordering, you could possibly find a case where a > b is true when both are treated as the type of object a, while a > b is false if both are treated as the type of object b ("10" > "9" vs 10 > 9 if you tried to compare "10" > 9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a relatively straightforward solution, but it does require you to edit all your existing uses of `==`.

Change this:

```
if a == b:
```

To this:

```
if isequal(a, b):

def isequal(a, b):
    assert type(a) == type(b)
    return a == b
```

Comment: `type(a)` rather than `isinstance(a)` is better here, because the latter will check for subclass while the former is more strict.